# SSDT 2017 Get Data - flat file source (csv/txt)

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

There are manay examples of new using modern Get Data feature while connecting to SQL Server. However, I can't find any examples of importing data from multiple flat files (csv/txt) located in one folder.
How should I make an initial connection to the data source? Whether it should be a connection to a folder or to one of the files? How should I buid the query chaing (query M).
It seems that the way I do it in Excel does not work.
I would be gratefull for any tips.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a couple Power BI examples.  Sorry, I misread that you wanted a Power Query/M language answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two good examples of how to import multiple text files with Power Query in Power BI.

Import all CSV files from a folder with their filenames in Power BI
https://powerpivotpro.com/2016/12/import-csv-files-folder-filenames-power-bi/

Power BI – Combine Multiple CSV files,Ignore Headers and Add FileName as a Column
http://analyticsavenue.com/power-bi-combine-multiple-csv-filesignore-headers-and-add-filename-as-a-column/

There are several ways to do this with standard SSIS tasks also, but I think the most flexible way is to use a Foreach Loop Container to read all the files in a folder.  In the properties of the Foreach Loop Container you specific the folder and a file name pattern (i.e. *.csv) of the files you want to import.

You create a variable to hold the name of the current file, and use that variable to change the Connection String property of the Flat File Source each iteration of the loop.

Here's a decent example of how to do this that covers most of the setup, and provides a downloadable example.

Loop through Flat Files in SQL Server Integration Services
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2874/loop-through-flat-files-in-sql-server-integration-services/